# Passing instance classes in WinJS

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm trying to pass a class instance about so that I can persist its member variables.  I have the following code

```
var mainNamespace = WinJS.Namespace.define("MainNamespace", {        
    setupClass: WinJS.Class.define(
        function () { },
        {
            createSetup: function CreateSetup() {                
                var interactionInst = new mainNamespace.interaction();

                drawScreen.DrawScreen(interactionInst);
                var backgroundProc = new 
                        mainNamespace.createProc(interactionInst);                
        }
    ),
    interaction: WinJS.Class.define(
        function() {},
        {
            clickedPos: 0,
            handleTouch: function handleTouch(event) {
                this.clickedPos = event.x;
                console.log("New pos: " + this.clickedPos);
        }
    ),

    createProc: WinJS.Class.define(
        function (interaction) {
            setInterval(this.runProc, 1000, interaction);
    },
    {

        runProc: function runNewProc(interaction) {
            console.log(interaction.clickedPos);
        }        
       ...
```

The `drawScreen` namepsace is as follows:

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("drawScreen", {
    DrawScreen: WinJS.Class.define(
    function DrawScreen(interaction) {
        /// Do some screen set-up here

        canvas.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", interaction.handleTouch, false);
    }
)


});
```

The problem I have is that the `interaction.clickedPos` never changes.  Why does it not change, and am I going about this the right way for a javascript app?

EDIT:

I've now worked out WHY this is happening, but not how to fix it.  When `interaction.handleTouch` fires, `this` refers to the `canvas` object, and NOT the `interaction` object - so I have no access to it's members.

Comment: not sure if it didnt paste right or not but the code above doesn't look right (to me anyways), missing commas? Also where is this.Interaction defined? Did you mean this.interaction? (note the case)

Comment: I think I've corrected that now - because I posted the classes in separately the commas must have gotten missed.  Yes, the interaction class is defined above.

Comment: Where do you wire up an event handler to the interaction.handleTouch method?

Comment: Sorry - updated again to show this

Comment: Drop a breakpoint inside of DrawScreen to ensure that gets hit. Secondly, set a breakpoint inside of handleTouch - is that ever getting hit? The syntax seems ok at a glance, although if you could have all the code for a reproduction via html sample,complete setup in DrawScreen, etc (theres missing items in both) it would be easier to test although try the breakpoints first.

Comment: There are sections of code missing, but I don't believe they are relevant to the question (getting the canvas context, etc...).

One of the first things that I did to debug this issue was to use breakpoints as you've described above.  The event listener does get set up and the `handleTouch` event is fired.  The problem is that when the `handleTouch` event changes this.clickedPos it doesn't persist.  My working theory is that I'm somehow not working with the same instance of the `interaction` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the following line:

`canvas.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", interaction.handleTouch, false);`

here you are passing a reference to the function handleTouch() without any connection to the current instance (interaction). You can change the context of the event handler by using the .bind() method:

`canvas.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", interaction.handleTouch.bind(interaction), false);`

Comment: Are you saying that passing `interaction.handleTouch` passes the function independently of the class it resides in?

Comment: Exactly. It just passes a reference to the function itself and the class it is in does not matter.